# Photography club: What to take with you?

Tags: clubs

I'm planning to join a photography club. What equipment do you take with you?

Do you take camera, lens, tripod and flash every time or you just pick your gear based on location?

I'm kind of lost what to take with me, since I don't know how do these clubs operate. Do they stick round in one place and shoot or move a lot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My experience from the two photo clubs I have been a member of, is that there are two kinds of gatherings. There are meetings where you just meet and don't photograph, and there are outings where you do photograph. Well, that's how swedes do it at least, there are of course variations.

If you are going to photograph, I would say that you generally just bring what you think that you might need. If you bring too much, people might think that you are just trying to show off, so keep it down at least until you have seen what the crowd is and what they bring.

Comment: Very good advice to get a feel for what a given club will bring when shooting, and how they go about it.  When we have our irregular street-photography get-togethers, we might be talking about a recent publication as often as going shooting, and if someone showed up with a tripod or 200mm zoom... that'd be a little odd, for sure.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience most photo club meetups are informal gatherings where people swap stories and get to know each other.  People do tend to take their cameras, but that's b/c we all love photography, and not really because you *need* it.  it's rare to see a tripod, extra lenses, etc.

Just have fun! In my experience photo clubs are a great way to learn new techniques, shooting locations.. almost anything.